# SDK tools button in Android Studio Get Not Clicked and Opened

Tags: android-studio

I am new to Android Studio (2.2.3) and after installation it.  I am getting this error of NDK Not Configured.

Although it does say to get it done via SDK Manager however when I go to SDK Manager the SDK Tools tab does not respond or operate.

Can anyone help me on it?

Answer (score 0):

[SDK manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvSmH.png)

There shouldn't a space in the android sdk location, I had the same problem, a space in the pc name as I had a space in "usama" and "azam". 
Be sure that you don't have a space in it.